# ajax post error when calling for hourly/daily/weekly/monthly data

Tags: php, html, jquery, post, http-post

I have a heat map application on OpenLayers where user enters two date and time intervals and selects whether he/she would like to view all the data between those two datetimes or view them based on hourly/daily/weekly/monthly intervals. However, when I type in two date and times as input and try to visualize the data, I can only visualize all the data between those two intervals. Whenever I choose hourly, daily, weekly etc from my HTML drop down menu and press fetch queries button, I get an Error in Ajax POST message. What could be the cause here? The codes are below:

The HTML Post part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 // ajaxForm submission
 $('#ajaxForm').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'heatQuery.php',
   //url: 'http://localhost/heatQuery.php',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response)
   {   
       // update the points for heatmap layer          
       updateHeatMap(response);

   },
   error: function(errorMsg)
   {
       alert('Error in Ajax POST');
       }


  });

  return false;
 });
});
```

The PHP Part:

setupDB.php

```
<?php

$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "myuser";
$mysql_password = "mypassword";
$mysql_database = "mydatabase";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");

?>
```

heatQuery.php

```
<?php
include 'setupDB.php';
$coords_array = array();

function getPoints($dateTimeBeg,$dateTimeEnd)
{
$ses_sql= "SELECT lat,lon FROM `mytable` WHERE calltime >= '$dateTimeBeg' AND calltime <= '$dateTimeEnd'";  
    $result = mysql_query($ses_sql,$bd) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    if($result)
    {
        $num_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num_of_rows > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            { 
                array_push($coords,array($row[0],$row[1]));     
            }
            array_push($coords_array,$coords);
        }
    }
}

$hours = array(1 => '00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00', '24:00');

$dateBeg = isset($_POST['date1']) ? $_POST['date1'] : "";
$dateEnd = isset($_POST['date2']) ? $_POST['date2'] : "";
$dateFreq = isset($_POST['freq']) ? $_POST['freq'] : "";

if($dateBeg && $dateEnd && $dateFreq) // if all variables are set
{
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($dateBeg);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($dateEnd);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2,true);

    if($dateFreq == "all")
    {
        $coords = array();
        $timeBeg = $_POST['time1'];
        $timeEnd = $_POST['time2'];
        $sp = " ";
        $dateTimeBeg = $dateBeg.$sp.$timeBeg;
        $dateTimeEnd = $dateEnd.$sp.$timeEnd;
        $ses_sql= "SELECT lat,lon FROM `mytable` WHERE calltime >= '$dateTimeBeg' AND calltime <= '$dateTimeEnd'";  
    $result = mysql_query($ses_sql,$bd) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    if($result)
    {
        $num_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num_of_rows > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            { 
                array_push($coords,array($row[0],$row[1]));     
            }
            array_push($coords_array,$coords);
        }
    }

    }else if($dateFreq == "hourly")
    {       
        for($i=1;$i<=24;$i+=1)
        {
            $coords = array();
            $timeBeg = $hours[$i];
            $timeEnd = $hours[$i+1];
            $dateTimeBeg = $dateBeg.$sp.$timeBeg;
            $dateTimeEnd = $dateBeg.$sp.$timeEnd;
            $ses_sql= "SELECT lat,lon FROM `mytable` WHERE calltime >= '$dateTimeBeg' AND calltime <= '$dateTimeEnd'";  
    $result = mysql_query($ses_sql,$bd) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    if($result)
    {
        $num_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num_of_rows > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            { 
                array_push($coords,array($row[0],$row[1]));     
            }
            array_push($coords_array,$coords);
        }
    }

        }
    }else if($dateFreq == "daily")
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=interval;$i+=1)
        {
            $ses_sql= "SELECT lat,lon FROM `mytable` WHERE calltime >= '$dateTimeBeg' AND calltime <= '$dateTimeEnd'";  
    $result = mysql_query($ses_sql,$bd) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    if($result)
    {
        $num_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num_of_rows > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            { 
                array_push($coords,array($row[0],$row[1]));     
            }
            array_push($coords_array,$coords);
        }
    }
        }
    }

    $coords_json = json_encode($coords_array);
    echo $coords_json;

//echo $coords;

    mysql_close($bd);
}

?>
```

EDIT:

Per bPratik's request, I'm also placing the alternative post error for HTML code that includes the error I get from the server:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
   {

       alert('Error in Ajax POST\ntextStatus: ' + textStatus + '\nerrorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
    }
```

Despite putting this, I only get the Error in AJAX Post message. The weird thing is, the mysqld.exe process runs for a while -apparently it actually retrieves the queries meanwhile- and then I get the message.

Comment: please also include the error you get.

Comment: with that I don't mean the error text you get from the callback, but instead any error you get from the server.

Comment: @bPratik how do I do that? I only get the 'Error in AJAX POST' message but I had a spare implementation with `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
   alert('Error in Ajax POST\ntextStatus: ' + textStatus + '\nerrorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
   //alert(jqXHR);
       }`, do you want to see the result of that one?

Comment: yes. include the result of that one as an edit to the question, not a comment.

Comment: @bPratik done, I edited.

Comment: Consider running this script on Chrome and use `chrome console` to locate the problem.
Anyway , replace `alert('Error in Ajax POST');` with `alert(errorMsg);` , what's the error now?

Comment: @OfirBaruch changed it, still getting the same Error in Ajax POST error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue some time ago, will post details soon.